# How to get the data of an activated row GTK+ C

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, glade

After the "row-activated" signal is activated , how to get the data of the selected row ? I'm using C language .

```
void on_treeview1_row_activated()
{
//I want to get the data here
}
```

Comment: This is not enough code to give a concrete answer. At least, you should add how your treeview is declared, initialized etc. Best way would be to create a [mcve].

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not able to post all the lines of codes because it is about 2000 line .I'm using glade to build the whole UI. The model of the tree view is a list store , the list store is populated through an SQLite embedded database . 

so my question is simple i think . when the row is selected , how to get the data contained in that row ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback prototype for the [`row-activated`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#GtkTreeView-row-activated) signal should be:

```
void user_function (GtkTreeView       *tree_view,
                    GtkTreePath       *path,
                    GtkTreeViewColumn *column,
                    gpointer           user_data)
```

This means that you will have references to the treeview (and related model/store) and the selected path. This should be enough to extract data from the activated row.

Supposing that your model/store has as first column some integers as ID and a second column with strings:

```
| ID |  TEXT      |
+----+------------+
| 12 | John Doe   |
...
| 35 | Whatever   |
+----+------------|
```

So your callback function should be something like this:

```
void on_treeview1_row_activated(GtkTreeView       *treeview, 
                                GtkTreePath       *path, 
                                GtkTreeViewColumn *column,
                                gpointer userdata) {

   gint int_data;
   gchar *str_data;

   GtkTreeIter iter;
   GtkTreeModel *model = gtk_tree_view_get_model(treeview);

   if (gtk_tree_model_get_iter(model, &iter, path)) {
      gtk_tree_model_get (GTK_LIST_STORE(model), &iter, 0, &int_data, 1, &str_data, -1));
      // Here the variables int_data and str_data should be filled with
      // relevant data
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without your code I can only give a rough direction:

In your callback you get a path to your row:

```
static void on_treeview1_row_activated(GtkTreeView       *tree_view,
                                GtkTreePath       *path,
                                GtkTreeViewColumn *column,
                                gpointer           user_data)
{
  ...
```

From there you can derive an iterator...

```
  GtkTreeIter   iter;
  if (gtk_tree_model_get_iter(GTK_TREE_MODEL(list_store), &iter, path))
  {
```

... and get the required fields from the list store:

```
    gtk_tree_model_get(GTK_TREE_MODEL(list_store), &iter, 
                       INDEX_field_1, &param1,
                       INDEX_field_2, &param2,
                       ...
                       -1);
  }
}
```